# CSS: Problema no Firefox e Chrome utilizando padding

Tags: css

Quando eu defino o `padding` de alguma `div` dá uma diferença de `1px`, eu estou construindo um menu, define o `padding` na `#menu ul li a` e a diferença de um navegador para o outro é mais `4 px`, existe algum hack para isso?

```
<body> 
 <section>
  <header>
  <nav id="menu">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li> 
    <li><a href="produtos.php">Produtos</a></li> 
    <li><a href="contato.php">Contato</a></li> 
    <li><a href="quemsomos.php">Sobre nos</a></li> 
   </ul> 
  </nav>
  </header> 
 <section> 
</body> 
</html>
```

```
   body {
     background-color:#87CEEB;
     width:100%;
     height:10%;
     }
   header {
     width:1100px;
     height:200px;
     background-color:white;
     margin-left:120px;
     }
   nav#menu ul {
         padding-top:209px;
     padding-left:2px;
    }
   nav#menu li{
    margin: -2px; /*TIRA O ESPAÇAMENTO DO MENU/ JUNTA OS*/
     }
   nav#menu ul li { 
    display: inline; /*DEIXA O MENU NA HORIZONTAL*/
    }
   nav#menu ul li a {
    background-color:#FFF68F;
    text-decoration: none; /*TIRA O ANDERLINE DO MENU*/
        padding-right:110px; /* DEFINE O TAMANHO DO MENU*/
        padding-left:110px;   /* DEFINE O TAMANHO DO MENU*/
    padding-bottom:10px;/* DEFINE O TAMANHO DO MENU*/
    padding-top:10px;/* DEFINE O TAMANHO DO MENU*/
    margin-top:6px;
}
```

Comment: Eu não gosto de usar hacks para nada, talvez haja algo em seu código que posse ser melhorado ou reorganizado. Poderia psotar o [~tag:css] e o [tag:html] para que possamos ver

Comment: Provavelmente o problema não está no padding, e sim em alguma outra coisa, como caracteres invisíveis ou diferença de altura de linha e/ou fontes (mesmo que seja só num espaço em branco). Queira editar a pergunta e postar o código que você está usando.

Comment: Se o teu html está exatamente assim, acho que te falta fechar o nav: `</nav>`

Comment: Fechei a nav, n é esse o problema, finalmente consegui postar o css, é a primeira vez q estou usando esse fórum.

Comment: A questão é que a fonte é renderizada diferente em cada navegador. Tendo assim cada fonte uma largura diferente. O ideal seria adicionar uma largura e altura fixa se quiser esse nível de exatidão, mas isso normalmente é aceitado por pessoas que entendem como funciona o desenvolvimento web.

Answer (score 3):

Acrescente as definições de fontes, e veja se ao menos fica igual em todos os browsers:

```
#menu ul, #menu ul li {font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px}
```

Comment: Algum tempo atrás tive o mesmo problema, mas não sabia nem o que pesquisar, sabe quando o professor pergunta qual sua dúvida? e você não sabe nem o que perguntar, hehehe comigo aconteceu isso, mas a primeira resposta, no caso, a de bacco resolveu meu problema, Vleu Bacco Deus te ajude irmão.

Answer (score 3):

O problema de espaçamento tem a ver com o tamanho das  palavras combinado com o *padding*. da forma que está o teu código simplesmente não encaixa. sempre vai dar algum problema desde como a fonte é renderizada até o box-model do navegador.

Uma opção é fazer como [neste exemplo que usa  flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/flexbox-bar-navigation/) e deixar o navegador calcular o espaçamento por você.

Ou rever o teu código (assim deu certo, mas não sei se te atende):

*no css:*

```
  -- css reset omitido --
  *{box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;}
  html{background-color:#87CEEB;}
  body{margin: 10px;}
  section{width:1100px;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
  header{height:200px;background-color:white;}
  nav li{
    float:left;
    width:275px;
    height:30px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  nav p {
    background-color:#FFF68F;
    height:50px;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
```

*no html:*

```
<section>
    <header></header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><p>Home</p></a></li> 
            <li><a href="#"><p>Produção</p></a></li> 
            <li><a href="#"><p>Contato</p></a></li> 
            <li><a href="#"><p>Sobre nos</p></a></li> 
        </ul> 
    </nav>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma técnica comum em CSS que é a utilização de um arquivo que "reseta" os valores padrões que os navegadores costumam colocar por padrão nos elementos, desta forma fica mais fácil acompanhar e evitar que qualquer comportamento diferente ocorre entre os navegadores:

Geralmente um reset.css vem com esses valores: [Usando RESET CSS](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/css-reset-o-que-e-e-como-usar/)

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
font-size: 100%;
vertical-align: baseline;
background: transparent;
}
body {
line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
content: '';
content: none;
}

:focus {
outline: 0;
}

ins {
text-decoration: none;
}
del {
text-decoration: line-through;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: Amigo, eu já tentei tudo qualquer tipo de reset, e isso não resolveu o problema. Obrigado pela atenção.